# How to use module in Guile? `$ guile copy.scm; ERROR: no code for module (gnome-2)`

Tags: gtk, fedora, gnome, guile

I learnt basisc about Scheme and want to try Guile.
When copied [this sample here the first one](https://sites.google.com/site/robertharamoto/Home/programming/graphics/guile-gnome/hello1) and run as a script, an Error occured,

```
$ guile copy.scm 
ERROR: no code for module (gnome-2)
```

My laptop runs Fedora 16 x86_64, with `yum install guile*`
How to deal with Guile's modules?

Comment: You need to install the Guile binding for gnome 2. AFAIK Fedora 16 ships with Gnome 3 (not sure if the support for Gnome 2 stuff are still available). Check for guile binding which have been installed (Maybe `yum list|grep -i guile|grep -i gnome`)

Comment: `gnutls-guile.i686 : 
gnutls-guile.x86_64 : 
graphviz-guile.x86_64 : 
guile-cairo.i686 : 
guile-cairo.x86_64 : 
guile-cairo-devel.i686 : 
guile-cairo-devel.x86_64 : 
guile-devel.i686 : 
guile-devel.x86_64 :
guile-lib.noarch :
guile.i686 :
guile.x86_64 :
libctl.i686 : 
libctl.x86_64`

Comment: `yum list` got nothing here, using `yum search | grep guile` these packages are listed. While I was searching. a package called `guile-gnome-platform` was mentioned several times, but I coundn't find it using `yum` on Fedora 16. I'm wondering if this metters or not?

Comment: Hmmm it may not be in the repositories of Fedora then. You could try building it from source

Answer (score 0):

May be you need [guile-gnome-plataform-devel](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/community/?search=guile-gnome#search)?